# Making a News reading app in Android Studio (WebView). but when ever i click a video in a selected article it does not play

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

Is their something i'm doing wrong? Do i have to include some lib?

I've tried adding the Youtube Api but that didn't help.

Edit#1: This is the WebView code

On some instance the Audio Playback works but instead of video it's just a rotating circle animation trying to load the video.

```
package com.PAKGN.Mizzy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

private WebView webView1;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private String title;
private String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    //  this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
     url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {

        webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);


        final Activity activity = this;


        webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

        {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                                    String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });

        webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Code for WebView goes here
                webView1.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });



    }


}



@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)).saveState(outState);
}





@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView1.canGoBack()) {
        webView1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

.

Comment: Please add here what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable javaScript.`WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

EDIT:
You are setting the WebClient for webview twice.

```
   `webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                                String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });`
```

You aren't really doing anything here thats different from the original implementation and this code isn't even running because you replace the webview with another webclient so delete this.

```
    ` runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Code for WebView goes here
            webView1.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

`

Delete this too, just type webview1.loadUrl(url) no need for a runOnUiThread.

```
    ` webView1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Delete this too, its this line that is causing your issue.  `

Comment: Where do i paste this?

Comment: On a fragments onCreateView, or an Activity's onCreate

Comment: Error:(32, 9) error: cannot find symbol class WebSettings

Comment: Alright so Imported the "import android.webkit.WebSettings;" but now on some site the audio is playing and not the video it;s just a loading cicrle animation and on some it says "If playback doesn't begin shortly restart your device"

Comment: I'll try to run on my device. Whats the web URL?

Comment: Should i send you an apk? So you can test the app on your device and see what really is the problem or should i email you my webview code?

Comment: Just edit your question and insert your code. There should be tabs showing brackets { } above the textbox.

Comment: Error:(71, 21) error: cannot find symbol method load(String)

Comment: web1view.loadUrl(String)

Comment: Error:(71, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable String

Comment: web1view.loadUrl(url)

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! :) IGN videos are playing great  also the pages seem to load faster. The only problem now is their are no controls and even if they are available they are not working. :p and is their any way i can enable hardware acceleration that can make the videos play smooth?

Comment: I seem to have controls working on my device when i visit IGN. As for hardware acceleration, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I can't play the video in full screen. That's the only issue also the IGN Video frame is cropped for some reason which hides the control

Comment: Also i tried Application level Hardware Accelration
and it gave this error
Error:The end-tag for element type "application" must end with a '>' delimiter.

Comment: Try visiting that video with your phones browser and see what happens.